# How to access a connected iPhone device from within Terminal?

Tags: iphone, mac, terminal, filesystem

How can I access the connected iPhone or iPad from within Terminal on OS X? I want to get all the photos (only photos) from the connected iDevice and save it to any directory in my OS X filesystem. I don't want to use the iTunes and instead just want to do it all within Terminal.

I want to get the file path like `/Volumes/my_iphone_name`, but for some reasons I didn't find anything such in `/Volumes` subdirectory. Also, `diskutil list` didn't get me anything that seems related to the connected device.

So where is there my iPhone detected on the entire filesystem?

Comment: I don't know how to do this but if you wan to get access to photos and such I use http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/

Comment: You can access a jailbroken iPhone through ssh. Is you iPhone jailbroken? Otherwise, it is impossible for now.

Comment: Thanks. My iPhone is not jailbroken and I don't like to jailbreak it.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the answer you're looking for, but apparently this can't be done. Please see this question: [iOS mount point in macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366322/ios-mount-point-in-macos-is-there-any-way-to-access-the-ios-files-in-macos-dir)

Answer (score 0):

There may not be a way to transfer the photos directly to your OS X filesystem from the iPhone/iPad using Terminal. However, if you have access to a Windows computer (at home, at your local library, etc.), you can plug the device into the Windows computer and access the photos in the device's DCIM folder via File Explorer. You can then transfer the desired photos (and videos, for that matter) to a flash drive. After that, all you have to do is connect the flash drive to your OS X device. Then you will be able to transfer the photos to wherever you would like on your OS X filesystem.